# Injecting CSS and JS into UiBinder - Issue with getting access to image path

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to implement a JS library (VisJs: http://visjs.org/) in my GWT project.
So, in order to use it from my UiBinder I used the ScriptInjector:

```
ScriptInjector.fromString(JsResources.INSTANCE.visScript().getText()).inject();
```

and in ui.xml I used the following:

```
<ui:style src='../../../resources/vis.min.css'> 
</ui:style>
```

in my project I created a folder called resources as follow:
[resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3Mev.png)

in my gwt.xml i added:

```
<resource path="resources" />
```

in order to get access to these resources.

The script is working for me and loading the graph, but not completely. I'm getting such errors:

vis.js:52995 GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/css/img/network/cross.png 404 (Not Found)
Somehow the "css" is part of the url and images can't be found!

B.R.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) Use `<ui:image>`. This lets you add a tag to the the ui.xml file which can be referenced elsewhere in your file, such as in your `<ui:style>` tag

```
<!-- With the name cross, it expects to find cross.png in the same dir.
     Otherwise, use the `src` attribute to point to the image file
     where it is in your project
-->
<ui:image ui:field="cross" />
<!-- Now in your css, you can use gwt-sprite, like you would in a
     normal css resource
-->
<ui:style>
  .cross-icon {
    gwt-sprite: 'cross';
    padding: 10px;
    /* etc */
  }
<ui:style>
```

This should be the preferred option, since it lets the compiler inline your image if it is small enough, reducing the number of requests your app makes to the server, improving load time.

2) Use the `public/` directory instead of resources, to indicate that the image should be outputted directly in your compiled app with no processing. To do this, make your `public/` directory parallel to the `client` package and the .gwt.xml file, and put the image in there. Then, you simply specify the path to the image, relative to your `app.nocache.js` file - it will be in the same output directory.